# google colab: how to get last editor of gdrive file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gdrive

I'm collecting gdrive file's meta data using colab like this.

```
!pip install kora
from kora.xattr import get_id
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread_dataframe as gd

import gspread
from google.auth import default
import pandas as pd
creds, _ = default()

import os
import time
import datetime
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

root_path = "/content/gdrive/myRoot/"

link = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/'
for (root, directories, files) in os.walk(root_path): 
    for file in files:
      ctime = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
      last_update = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(ctime), "%c")
      file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
      fid = get_id(file_path)
```

I want to know how to get last editor information.

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) Also, by "editor", I assume you mean the last user that edited the file, not the program that opened it up for editing (such as a text editor).

Comment: Yes, I want to know the email address of the last person who edited file.

Comment: I tried to get it through the Google Drive API( using PyDrive module). But I can't find a way to get the last edited person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Google Drive API reference page for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) you simply need to query the file's metadata using the `lastModifyingUser.emailAddress` key.